# Изменить картинку при наведении мыши на другую только посредством CSS?

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий код

```
<img  class="big" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1JcY0l5Gh3aLU-oZXdNxJrYxvZ_MfOlc4J5p2TtNlHgjYnzymGKoxCRTy"><img>
<br>
<div class="tooltip"><img class="small" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1JcY0l5Gh3aLU-oZXdNxJrYxvZ_MfOlc4J5p2TtNlHgjYnzymGKoxCRTy"><div>Постоянство памяти</div><img></div>
<div id="one" class="tooltip"><img class="small" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5UltE5sOS7IbBObarHd1wfGy5mTaiH2KNuLYL8Yup5KwAabm-ulok0tfa"><div>Глаза-очки</div></img></div>
<div id="two" class="tooltip"><img class="small" src="http://www.wm-painting.ru/plugins/p17_image_gallery/images/2/483.jpg"><div>Взрыв</div></img></div>
```

Необходимо сделать, чтобы при наведении на какой-либо img с классом small, изображение с классом big менялось на выделенное, используя только средства CSS?

Через JS это можно и легко, но как сделать в этом случае?

Comment: Нет, на css это сделать не получится. Можно делать через sibling, но придется прописывать в css все пути к изображениям и заменять бекграунд чего-то.
CSS - это только отображение. Здесь необходимо управление + работа с данными (вытягивание адресов больших картинок).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так не подойдет - http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover ?
А для удобства я бы рекомендовал на jsfiddle оформить.